# How to enable CodeReload for dependency with :path specified

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Let's say I have phoenix app and a library I'm working on in some directory:

```
defp depts do
  [
    {:phoenix, "~> 1.3.0"},
    {:my_lib, path: "../whatever"}
  ]
end
```

While that works fine, any changes done to the `my_lib` requires server restart. Is there a way to force code reload on that somehow?

Comment: I ended up symlinking it into /lib instead of defining in the mixfile. It works, I guess?

Comment: Symlinking definitely works, as well as umbrella project. It depends on how you would go with the codebase later.